# AngularJS share copied object across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS project, I am not able to share data of copied objects across different controllers.

I am able to share data properly if I set the properties in code but if I copy the object then it does not appear to work.

In the code block at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gunjankarun/2UAd9/), you will see that I have two objects `User` and `OriginalUser`.
As soon as the `FirstCtrl` is loaded, I copy the `User` object to the `OriginalUser` object.

You will see that while the value assigned to `User` object in `FirstCtrl`is accessible in `SecondCtrl` but the data of `OriginalUser` is accessible only in the `FirstCtrl`.

You can see the code in action at [Code Sample at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gunjankarun/2UAd9/)

Comment: First inject rootdata into your first controller, and copy your object into it. Then this it will be available for other controllers.

Comment: @saidomar What is "rootdata"?

Comment: Sorry i would mean rootscope http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope...

Comment: I see. Btw, using $rootScope to share data is a bad practice (similar to global namespace pollution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not update OriginalUser data but you create a new variable using angular.copy function.

What you are looking for is angular.extend which will copy user properties to your original user. Now, both controllers use the same object instance.

Your first controller:

```
function FirstCtrl($scope,User, OriginalUser){
    $scope.user = User;
    $scope.o_user = angular.extend(OriginalUser, $scope.user);
}
```

Your fiddle is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, this works. I will accept this answer as soon as the 6 minute limit is over.